# Low Input Voltage DC DC Converter to Power LEDs

Tags: dc-dc-converter

The LEDs in my circuit need 3.0V-3.2V  to be illuminated. Energy generated from using a DC motor as a generator and is stored in 1 Farad capacitors with a maximum voltage of 5.5V. I am looking to implement a DC DC converter that will take extremely low voltages (between 0V and around 3V) and increase the voltage above the minimum for the LEDs to extend the time of illumination. The converter needs to be on the small side, as all of this will be packaged in a 3D printed case assembly that can easily be hand-held.

Does anyone have suggestions on specific products or things to keep in mind? I understand that most converters require a minimum voltage to be able to perform their function. Also, would a simple boost converter be preferable over a converter that regulates the voltage at a steady output above the approximate 3V minimum for the LEDs?

Comment: Are you doing a class project, or are you a maker doing just a hobby circuit? If the answer is yes, I suggest that you use the ubiquitous "Joule Thief" (google it), it is a simple circuit that converts voltage and can light leds from a voltage so low as 0.9 V. But if you are doing a "serious" circuit, your question could be more explanative. How much leds? Which time do you want the leds turned on? Research about JOULE THIEF, maybe it will be the easiest solution for all your problems.

Comment: @mguima Should he answer "yes" to an or question? On a more serious note, I second mguima's recommendation for researching joule thief.

Comment: @mguima This is an interdisciplinary project at my college I am working on. We are making a battery free light source. With capacitors completely discharged, we need to be able to crank our generator (DC motor) for two minutes and have 30 minutes of ample lighting. After that 30 minutes, another 1 minute of cranking must produce the same performance. We will most likely have between 6-9 ChanZon 5mm white LED's. I will research the JOULE THIEF for our application.

Comment: For this requirements, I think that joule thief will be the easiest solution. Maybe a rechargeable battery would perform better than the 1 farad capacitor. Think about adding gears in order to spin the generator faster and get more energy.

Comment: @Harry, in fact "yes" applies for both questions. My mistake! ;-)   I should have said "Are you doing a class project, or are you a maker doing just a hobby circuit? If the answer is yes for one of those two questions, I suggest (...) But if the answer is NO to both questions, so you are doing a 'serious' circuit (...)"

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your definition of "extend the time of illumination".

If your regulator pulls enough power to keep the LEDs up at the nominal 3V you may actually reduce the time of illumination compared to letting the LED dim with the voltage.

However, the best way to implement this type of requirement is to use an LED driver. There are numerous varieties available on the market.

These work by drawing enough current from the source to drive the LEDs at the current you define to get your desired brightness. They differ from traditional DC-DC convertors in that they are current regulators not voltage regulators.

Again, whether that increases time of illumination is debatable, especially when you now have to add in the efficiency of the regulator.

Comment: Thanks @BlairFonville, odd it didn't flag that..

Comment: We are planning on doing a dual-function light setup, one with more concentrated light and another with a dimmer but wider radial setup. The power required for an acceptable amount of illumination will depend on our exact light setup, so more testing with LED holder designs will be required before that can be quantified. I will look into the LED drivers you suggested, thank you for the insight.